# Mule not displaying/reading custom messages from ReloadableResourceBundles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mule

I can't figure out how to get my custom message from the Spring Errors object.  It seems like I have stuff wired up properly.  I've seen examples where the default message is actually the custom message, but that seems a hack and contrary to the documentation.

As I understand it, using ValidationUtils, I could have the following:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "myfield", "myfield.required", "Column 'myfield' is required.");
```

I also think I understand that the second parameter "myfield.required" is in essence the key to a properties file entry.

So, I have this properties file sitting my src/main/resouces folder named *validation-messages_en_US.properties* with this entry:

```
myfield.required=Column 'myfield' is a custom message !
```

My Spring Bean definition:

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myproject" />
    <spring:bean id="messageSource" name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <spring:property name="basenames" value="classpath:validation-messages"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

My Validator:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Payload;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.mycompany.myproject.vsd.request.VSDRequest;

@Component
public class VSDRequestValidator implements Validator {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VSDRequestValidator.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return VSDRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {

        VSDRequest request = (VSDRequest) object;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "myfield", "myfield.required", "Column 'myfield' is required.");

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            List<ObjectError> objErrors = errors.getAllErrors();
            for (ObjectError e : objErrors) {
                logger.info(e.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Receive <code>payload</code> to perform validations on.
     * 
     * @param object
     */
    public void validate(@Payload Object object) {

        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The supplied [Validator] is required and must not be null.");
        }

        if (!supports(object.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The supplied [Validator] must support the validation of [VSDRequest] instances.");
        }

        BeanPropertyBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult((VSDRequest) object, "VSDRequest");

        logger.info(messageSource.getMessage("myfield.required", null, null));  // This get the message I want

        validate(object, errors);
    }

}
```

My MessageSource properly injects.  I injected it into my class just to check it and know it's being recognized. I shouldn't even need to do that if Spring is reading the ReloadableResourceBundle.

Does the getDefaultMessage() return either the custom message or the default message? Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong?